# Laravel: does the migration file run one time only between migrate and rollback?

Tags: php, laravel, migration

In a Laravel project I wrote the following up() in a create table migration file:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and run the migration command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

and the table created successfully, then I created another migration file for modifying my table adding a new column and wrote the following up():

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('name');
    });
}
```

and as expected the column is added successfully.

My problem is when I modify the last file to add a new column

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('address');
    });
}
```

and running:

```
php artisan migrate
```

the command gave me **Nothing to migrate**, so shall I create a new migration file for each single modification or shall I run one of the commands

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

or

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

to get my modifications? but in the last commands the data would be lost and I don't want this to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this answer.

**As long as you are still in development:** Yes, you can feel free to edit your migration and roll it back and forth until you are satisfied with the outcome.

**Once your migration has been executed elsewhere (e.g. production system):** You should never ever change that migration again. The point here is to have a mechanism that can replay the changes in the structure. Laravel uses a very simple "did I run this migration already?"-functionality to see which parts of the migrations it still has to run for that database. Hence, the same migration will never be run in the future again.

TL;DR: For your question

> shall i create a new migration file for each single modification

one could say: yes!

Comment: thank you bro for your answer,  i can easily then modify my database creating multiple modification files if this is the only way i just was looking for what is the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

As ArSen said as long as you are **still in development**, you can just modify the `migration` files such as combine them all in a single file like

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('address');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Then **run** this in your  terminal from [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations)

`php artisan migrate:fresh`

Answer (score 0):

when you develop locally it is normal that "migration file" is updated. 
After each update you must do first or second thing :

```
run php artisan migrate:rollback --step=1 WITH OLD VERSION of migration file, after 
that change migration file as you wish and run "php artisan migrate" again
```

or

```
manually delete record from migrations table, and manually delete all changes that 
migration produced (e.g. delete db table) and after that just run "php artisan migrate"
```

Comment: thank you first for your answer :) i would use the first choice if i developed locally as you said and if there was no worry about losing my data, in the second choice deleting the migration file is a good idea to make laravel runs the file again but deleting all changes  may mean deleting a table as you said and i think that could make an error in other tables if they had e.g. foreign key pointing to a column in the deleted table so if for example i rename the table the other tables won't be affected by that.